# Inconsistent (apparently) behaviour with static members in F#

Tags: f#, static-members

The following first 2 F# snippets get different results, but I find this a little inconsistent, even though I understand that members and values have different semantics. I would expect both of them getting the same results (the second one, as they have a similar value syntax).

IMHO the third snippet, which explicitly defines a get method, should be differentiated from the first.

Am I alone?

```
let mutable b = 0

type A = A with
    static member B = 
        b <- b + 1
        b

printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B

//1
//2
//3
```

```
let mutable b = 0

type A = A

let _b = 
    b <- b + 1
    b

type A with
    static member B = _b

printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B

//1
//1
//1
```

```
let mutable b = 0

type A = A with
    static member B 
        with get() = 
            b <- b + 1
            b

printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B

//1
//2
//3
```

**EDIT**

I agree with Tomas, the syntax is a little misleading. However I can see where the dilemma is: while the value syntax is F#/functional, the member notation must replicate the .NET/Object Oriented behaviour.

For those interested, value-behaving static member can be a pattern:

```
type MyType = MyType

let private myValueBehavingStaticPropertyValue = 
... potentially heavy workflow

type MyType with 
    static member MyValueBehavingStaticProperty = myValueBehavingStaticPropertyValue
```

with this, the 'potentially heavy workflow' is not repeated every time we read the property

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. It's like you said: values and properties have different semantics. Properties are essentially functions, while values are, well, values. If you want a member that behaves like a value, define a field instead of a property.

Comment: `member` are methods which reevaluates at each access. So if body of property changes something, it will change it every time. You can read more in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Can DU have fields? And if they could, F# fields (defined as let fields = ...) are not accessible externally, hence you need to define a companion member.

Comment: @FrancoTiveron, what was you trying to do in the first place? Adding field to DU seems strange. `type A = | A of B:int * C:float` is valid and can be deconstructed with `let (A(B=x; C=y)) = (A (10, 20.0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is a good one. The definition of a static property is syntactically very similar to definition of a value - so I can see why you think the two should behave the same.

This is slightly misleading, because behind the senes, properties have a getter method that is evaluated each time the property is accessed. As a minimal example, in the following, accessing `A1.B` twice prints "hi" twice:

```
type A1 = A1 with
  static member B = 
    printfn "hi"

A1.B; A1.B
```

There is actually a more verbose syntax for properties in F#, which reveals what is going on - the fact that `B` is actually backed by a `get()` method that is invoked by the compiled code behind the scenes:

```
type A2 = A2 with
  static member B 
    with get() = printfn "hi"

A2.B; A2.B
```

Now, you would never actually do this in practice, but you can even invoke the method (which is hidden from IntelliSense) directly:

```
A2.get_B(); A2.get_B()
```

Comment: You are the only one who really understood my question!

Answer (score 2):

> The following first 2 F# snippets get different results, but I find this a little inconsistent, even though I understand that members and values have different semantics. I would expect both of them getting the same results (the second one, as they have a similar value syntax).

You're expecting that evaluating `_b` caused it to re-evaluate itself, but that's not how values evaluate in F#. If I define `let x = 12` it doesn't re-evaluate what `x` is each time I access it.

That's why it always prints `1`. When `_b` is first accessed, it is evaluated once and that's it.

> IMHO the third snippet, which explicitly defines a get method, should be differentiated from the first.

Why? It's no different than the first snippet. An F# property defined like so:

```
type A =
    static member X = 12
```

Is compiled with a getter just like if you define it explicitly.

Comment: @Phiilip no I am not expecting that _b get re-evaluated. I would understand if static member X = 12 doesn't get re-evaluated (while member X with get() does). I know that this is not how it works, but just looking at the syntax, the first looks exactly as a value definition, the second more as a function, that's all. I found myself writing the value-like static member definition and noticing how it looks similar to a plain value definition. Probably I am the only one

Answer (score 1):

Your second version is **not** equivalent to either the first or the third. This is:

```
let mutable b = 0

type A = A

let _b () = 
    b <- b + 1
    b

type A with
    static member B = _b ()

printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B

//1
//2
//3
```

`_b` here is identified as a *function* and not a *value* (as in your case) and so is invoked each time you call the static member via `A.B`. So I would say this apparent inconsistency is only apparent as long as one confuses identifiers of *values* (which are only evaluated once) versus *functions* (which are evaluated only and each time they are invoked).

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet:

```
let mutable b = 0

type A = A

let _b = 
    b <- b + 1
    b

type A with
    static member B = _b

printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
printfn "%d" A.B
```

`_b` gets the value 1, regardless of everything that comes after it. `_b` will never get re-evaluated. So while the property A.B itself is re-evaluated all the time, it will just return the value `_b` that is set already set in stone.